# sweetalert2 failed to call Confirm POST submit button in Laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel, sweetalert2

In my Laravel-5.8, I have this post request which I want to confirm using Sweetalert2

```
< script type = "text/javascript" >

  $(document).ready(function() {

    $("#hrbp_yearend_approve-form").submit(function(e) {

      $("#hrbp_yearend_approve_btn-submit").attr("disabled", true);
      $('#hrbp_yearend_approve_btn-submit').html('Processing...');

      return true;
    });
  }); 
</script> 

<script type = "text/javascript" >
  function submitFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("yearendSubmit");

    if (y == 1) {
      Swal('Oops...', 'You cannot submit this review rating!', 'error')

    } else {
      Swal({
        title: 'Are you sure?',
        text: 'This action will submit the employee review rating!',
        type: 'warning',
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonText: 'Yes, submit it!',
        cancelButtonText: 'No, dont submit it'
      }).then((result) => {
        if (result.value) {
          Swal(
            'Review Rating!',
            'The employee review rating has been recalledsuccessfully done.',
            'success'
          )
          x.style.display = "none";
        } else if (result.dismiss === Swal.DismissReason.cancel) {
          Swal(
            'Cancelled',
            'The employee review rating is safe :)',
            'error'
          )
        }
      })

    }
  } <
  /script>


<form action="{{ route('appraisal.appraisal_year_end_setups.hrbp_year_end_review_approve', ['id' => $goalmanager->employee_id]) }}" method="post" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="hrbp_yearend_approve-form">
  {{csrf_field()}}
  <div class="card-body">
    <input type="hidden" value="{{$count_ratings}}">

    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <table id="msfTable" class=" table table-bordered table-striped table-hover datatable">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col" class="text-center" width="30%" colspan="{{$count_ratings}}">Rating<span style="color:red;">*</span></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            @foreach($ratings as $rating)
            <th scope="col">
              {{$rating->rating_description}} ({{$rating->rating_value}}) 
            </th>
            @endforeach
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            @foreach($ratings as $index => $rating)
            <td align="center">
              <input type="radio" name="appraisal_rating_id" value="{{$rating->id}}" id="{!! $rating->id !!}" @if (!$index) {!! "unchecked" !!} @endif required>
            </td>
            @endforeach
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div id="yearendSubmit" class="float-left">
      <button type="submit" id="hrbp_yearend_approve_btn-submit" onclick="submitFunction()" class="btn btn-primary"> <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i> Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

When I submitted the POST request form, I expected sweetalert2 confirmation before being posted. Also, expects the button to display processing... until it is posted to the database.

The data got posted to the database, but the sweetalert2 confirmation and the processing... did not appear.

How do I resolve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems with your script:

1. You are calling the `Swal()` function with a capital S, whereas the function you are looking for is [`swal()`](https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/#getting-started).
2. the variable `y` is not defined.

Additionally, it's better to define your two snippets of JS code in the same call, as they need to be fired at the same event.

The code below should work:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#hrbp_yearend_approve-form").submit(function (e) {
      $("#hrbp_yearend_approve_btn-submit").attr("disabled", true);
      $("#hrbp_yearend_approve_btn-submit").html("Processing...");
      
      var x = document.getElementById("yearendSubmit");

      y = 1;
      if (y == 1) {
        swal("Oops...", "You cannot submit this review rating!", "error");
      } else {
        swal({
          title: "Are you sure?",
          text: "This action will submit the employee review rating!",
          type: "warning",
          showCancelButton: true,
          confirmButtonText: "Yes, submit it!",
          cancelButtonText: "No, dont submit it",
        }).then((result) => {
          if (result.value) {
            swal(
              "Review Rating!",
              "The employee review rating has been recalledsuccessfully done.",
              "success"
            );
            x.style.display = "none";
          } else if (result.dismiss === Swal.DismissReason.cancel) {
            swal("Cancelled", "The employee review rating is safe :)", "error");
          }
        });
      }

      return true;
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>

<form
  action="{{ route('appraisal.appraisal_year_end_setups.hrbp_year_end_review_approve', ['id' => $goalmanager->employee_id]) }}"
  method="post"
  class="form-horizontal"
  enctype="multipart/form-data"
  id="hrbp_yearend_approve-form"
>
  <div class="card-body">
    <input type="hidden" value="{{$count_ratings}}" />

    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <table
        id="msfTable"
        class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover datatable"
      >
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th
              scope="col"
              class="text-center"
              width="30%"
              colspan="{{$count_ratings}}"
            >
              Rating<span style="color: red">*</span>
            </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">
              Description1 (value1)
            </th>
            <th scope="col">
              Description2 (value2)
            </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td align="center">
              <input type="radio" name="appraisal_rating_id"
              value="1" id="1" required>
            </td>
            <td align="center">
              <input type="radio" name="appraisal_rating_id"
              value="2" id="2" required>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div id="yearendSubmit" class="float-left">
      <button
        type="submit"
        id="hrbp_yearend_approve_btn-submit"
        class="btn btn-primary"
      >
        <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i> Submit
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onsubmit` this will get called when submit button is clicked so inside `submitFunction()` you can write logic to return `true` or `false` depending on this form will submit . Then, you have typo there is no `Swal` its `swal` change it .Also, i have change some code inside your function to add `attr` to submit button and remove it ..etc.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
function submitFunction() {
  var flag = false; //declare this
  var x = document.getElementById("yearendSubmit");
  var y = 0
  //your submit..
  $("#hrbp_yearend_approve_btn-submit").attr("disabled", true);
  $('#hrbp_yearend_approve_btn-submit').html('Processing...');

  if (y == 1) {
    swal('Oops...', 'You cannot submit this review rating!', 'error')
    flag = false;
  } else {
    //use buttons 
    swal({
      title: 'Are you sure?',
      text: 'This action will submit the employee review rating!',
      icon: 'warning',
      buttons: true,
      buttons: ["No, dont submit it", "Yes, submit it!"],
    }).then((result) => {
      //check if true
      if (result) {
        swal(
          'Review Rating!',
          'The employee review rating has been recalledsuccessfully done.',
          'success'
        )
        x.style.display = "none";
        flag = true; //set flag to true
      } else if (!result) {
        //not true
        swal(
          'Cancelled',
          'The employee review rating is safe :)',
          'error'
        )
        flag = false; //set flag to false
        $("#hrbp_yearend_approve_btn-submit").attr("disabled", false)
        $('#hrbp_yearend_approve_btn-submit').html('<i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i> Submit')
      }
    })

  }
  return flag;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/2.1.2/sweetalert.min.js" integrity="sha512-AA1Bzp5Q0K1KanKKmvN/4d3IRKVlv9PYgwFPvm32nPO6QS8yH1HO7LbgB1pgiOxPtfeg5zEn2ba64MUcqJx6CA==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!--put onsubmit here-->
<form action="{{ route('appraisal.appraisal_year_end_setups.hrbp_year_end_review_approve', ['id' => $goalmanager->employee_id]) }}" method="post" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="hrbp_yearend_approve-form" onsubmit="return submitFunction()">
  <!--your other codes-->
  <div id="yearendSubmit" class="float-left">
    <button type="submit" id="hrbp_yearend_approve_btn-submit" class="btn btn-primary"> <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i> Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```